# Creating PdfFont in IText7

Tags: itext

We are evaluating Itext7 (hence I am fairly new to IText7) and would like to change the font in a table. Of course changing the font on the table is easy once I have the font, however creating the font is challenging. I have found simple examples 

   `font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ITALIC, PdfEncodings.WINANSI);`

but I would like to control the size, family, etc. of the font as well. I have found examples for previous versions of Itext that seem pretty straightforward. 

  `BaseFont helvetica = BaseFont.createFont(HELVETICA, CP1252, EMBEDDED);
  Font font = new Font(helvetica, 12, Font.NORMAL);`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iText 7 is fairly new. There's [iText 7: Jump-Start tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial) to get you started, but we still need to write many tutorials about specific aspects of iText 7.

Fortunatly, the question you've posted has already been dealt with in the second iText 7 tutorial [iText 7: Building Blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks). The information you need is in [Chapter 1: Introducing the PdfFont class](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1-introducing-pdffont-class).

When you read this chapter, you'll understand that the size of the font shouldn't be a property of the `PdfFont` class. Instead, you define the font size at the level of the object that uses this font.

For instance:

```
Text title1 = new Text("The Strange Case of ").setFontSize(12);
Text title2 = new Text("Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde").setFontSize(16);
Text author = new Text("Robert Louis Stevenson");
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().setFontSize(8)
    .add(title1).add(title2).add(" by ").add(author);
document.add(p);
```

In this case, `"The Strange Case of "` has a font size of 12; `"Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde"` has a font size of 16; `" by "` and `"Robert Louis Stevenson"` have a font size of 8, because that size is defined at the level of the `Paragraph`. The font size of `" by "` is the font size of the `Paragraph`. No font size was defined for `"Robert Louis Stevenson"`, which means that this `Text` object *inherited* the font size of the `Paragraph` to which it belongs.

I'm currently working on chapter 2. You'll notice that iText 7 now allows you to change the default font size for a `Document` by defining the font at the `Document` level. This is one of the many improvements of iText 7.

Comment: Bruno. I have to learn about iText7. I have seen that you have written some books about it. Would you advise me to use Java or C#? I have a basic knowledge of both languages. Thank you for your help!